# Highcharts data plugin decimal separator

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If got the highcharts 3 data plugin to read the values from a table. This not the problem for English because of the . for the decimal separator. In dutch the table uses a , as decimal separator. The graph don't show because of data plugin can't see 5,5 is the same as 5.5.

This is my javascript code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$('#grafiek620').highcharts({  
  chart: {  
    type: 'bar'  
  },  
  credits: {  
    enabled: false  
  },
  data: {  
    table: document.getElementById('datatable620')  
  },  
  title: {  
    text: jQuery('#datatable620').data('labeltitle')  
  },  
  xAxis: {  
    labels: {  
      rotation: 0  
    },  
    title: {  
      text: jQuery('#datatable620').data('labelx')  
    }  
  },  
  yAxis: [{  
    min: 0,  
    title: {  
      text: jQuery('#datatable620').data('labely')  
    },  
    labels: {  
      rotation: 0  
    }  
  }, {  
    opposite: true,  
    title: {  
      text: jQuery('#datatable620').data('labelz')  
    },  
  }],  
  legend: {  
    layout: "horizontal"  
  }  
});
```

I have added a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/knscs/

Comment: You get the datas as strings ?

Comment: the highcharts data plugin is reading a table from the website.

Comment: Ok, but javascript will not understand `1,23` as a number because of the coma... So as it reads, I thing it gets strings. You should convert you "numbers" to the Number type first. Can you give me what is the result of `jQuery('#datatable620').data('labelx')` ?

Comment: i'll make a js fiddle with a example

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/knscs/) jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/knscs/

Comment: It can't work because `table` option do not take HTMLElement, it takes javascript Object : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have one solution here :

```
var ConvertStringToFloat = function( datas ) {
    return datas.map(function(i, el) {
        var str = $(el).text();
        return parseFloat(str.replace(",", "."));
    });
}
ConvertStringToFloat ( $("td", $('#datatable620') ) )
```

Here you have an array of float, now you just have to create a series with HighChart.

```
series: [{
    data: ConvertStringToFloat ( $("td", $('#datatable620') ) )        
}]
```

**Here a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/knscs/3/**

To display the number (in the Dutch way), you have the ability to do that in the options of `Highcharts` :

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        decimalPoint: ','
    }
});
```

*PS : The name of the functions are of your choice... I didn't really think about it but `ConvertStringToFloat` is not a good choice ;)*

Comment: Only problem with this solution is that the parsing of the series is not good. There are 2 series: primair and secundair.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to change those commas to periods for this to work. Javascript isn't very good with cultural variations in number formats. A simple `string.replace` should do it.

For example, a very cheap and hacky way to do it with your example would be:

```
$("td").each(function() {
    var str = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(str.replace(',','.'));
});
```

Which changes all the `,` to `.` in your `td` tags, but it's not very smart and you should be very careful if your code needs to be international friendly and your encounter data like `1,000.5` or if you have a `td` with a string that includes commas.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit data.src.js module to allow working this with comas. What is good with editing source of that? You don't need to change anything in HTML, you don't have to loop through all item of array once again, simple find that line (in data.src.js):

```
floatVal = parseFloat(val);
```

And use `replace()` to replace `,` with `.` as other answers suggest.